# How to use a member into an override method called in the super constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, nullpointerexception, overriding

I have a NullPointerException when I try to do something like that :

```
class A {

  public A() {
    aMethod();
  } 

  public void aMethod() {
    //Some stuff
  }

}

class B extends A {

  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>

  public B() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void aMethod() {
    super.aMethod();
    list.add("Something"); //NullPointerException
  }

}
```

I can't instantiate the list before call super in the constructor, and I think it's not proper to instantiate it into the "aMethod".

Comment: In my opinion, this is a faulty design, because the extender of `A` has to know the implementation detail of `A` that `aMethod` is directly called in the constructor and therefore in `aMethod`, no fields can be used without explicitely initialising them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This illustrates the dangers of calling a subclass method through polymorphism from a superclass constructor.

Your `B` constructor calls `A`'s constructor explicitly, which calls `aMethod`.  But at this point, nothing in `B` is initialized yet, so `list` is still `null`.  That causes the `NullPointerException`.  Java won't initialize instance variables until after the call to the superclass constructor has completed.

The best way to solve this is to move the initialization of the list into the constructor:

Method:

```
super();
list.add("Something"); // No more NullPointerException
```

It's also best not to call methods that can be overridden in constructors, because in the superlcass constructor, the subclass portion of the object hasn't been initialized yet.